# Durable Functions: How to pass a parameter to the Orchestrator?

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

I am new to Azure Durable functions and have been following the sample code in the book ['Azure Serverless Computing Cookbook'](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Azure-Serverless-Computing-Cookbook-Third-Edition) and I am stuck because the .GetInput function in my Orchestrator is return null.  My Blob trigger is passing the file name as a parameter in the call to my Orchestrator.  I think its calling the wrong overloaded function but not sure how to call the correct one.

```
await starter.StartNewAsync("CSVImport_Orchestrator", name);
```

```
        [FunctionName("CSVImport_Orchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();
            string CSVFileName = context.GetInput<string>(); //<<== returns null???
            {
                List<Employee> employees = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<Employee>>("ReadCSV_AT", CSVFileName);
            }
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("CSVImportBlobTrigger")]
        public static async  void Run([BlobTrigger("import-obiee-report/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnection")]Stream myBlob, string name, [DurableClient]IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("CSVImport_Orchestrator", name); 
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
```

In advance, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are calling the [non-generic overload of `StartAsync(string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationclient.startnewasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_Extensions_DurableTask_IDurableOrchestrationClient_StartNewAsync_System_String_System_String_) where the second, `string` argument represents the InstanceId and not the input argument. There's also a [generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationclient.startnewasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_Extensions_DurableTask_IDurableOrchestrationClient_StartNewAsync__1_System_String___0_) where the second argument represents the data. You are passing a `string` so overload resolution sees two potential candidates. It then prefers the non-generic one since it's an **exact** match, thus "losing" your data.

If you *really* need a `string` for your input data you will need to specify the generic argument *explicitly* to force the compiler to select the correct overload:

```cs
await starter.StartAsync<string>("CSVImport_Orchestrator", name);
```

Now, the documentation also states that the input should be a JSON-serializeable *object*. Technically a `string` is, but I'm not sure how it plays with the orchestrator's serializer. You can instead pass a class containing your data. This has the upside that the generic argument will be properly *inferred*:

```cs
public class Data {
   public string Name { get; set; } 
} 

// calling 
await starter.StartAsync("CSVImport_Orchestrator", new Data { Name = name });

// using 
var csvFileName = context.GetInput<Data>()?.Name;
```

Comment: I like your class idea instead.  Can you explain 'public record Data(string Name)'?  (It didn't compile.)

Comment: It's a c#9 feature called records. That line declares a class with a single public property called "Name". But as I'm responding to you I realize azure functions cannot run on net5 and even if you use the latest compiler it won't support the new features. I've updated the example to use a full class. Sorry about that

Comment: Using your class idea worked!  Thank you very much!